# how to format chart_flutter line chart axis label

Tags: flutter, charts

I am currently using google's flutter chart library ([chart_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)) to create simple line chart. I want to format my own x-axis label. I have tried to use the charts.NumericAxisSpec to customize, but i cannot figure out how to use own formater instead of using their existing format.

[image]

This is the code i have tried:

```
charts.LineChart(data,
                domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(tickFormatterSpec:charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec.fromNumberFormat(numberFormat),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

customize x axis label, directly use BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec primary construtor:

```
charts.LineChart(data,
            domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(tickFormatterSpec:
charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num? value) {...}),
)
```